# Rails validates_format_of :username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
 validates_format_of :username, :with => /\A[a-zA-Z_]{2,35}\Z/
```

I am using the above to validate usernames but I want to change it as it is not good enough for my app. what I need is:

1. allow letters only or letters with underscore (nothing else)
2. letters should be all small caps
3. string does not start or end with underscore (underscore may appear in between letters only)
4. only one underscore is allowed
5. username characters limit is 35

I have tried several ways and I could not do it could someone help me out please?

Comment: please go and do the homework yourself: http://rubular.com/

Comment: i'm trying to help you by providing a helpful internet resource so that you can figure out yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following, assuming that "small caps" means lower case:

```
validates :username, length: { maximum: 35 }, format: { with: /\A[a-z]+_?[a-z]+\z/ }
```